# Calling an Azure Function with authentication from a Logic App using Managed Identities

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App that is using a Managed Service Identity (MSI). That logic app is attempting to call an Azure Function that has App Service Authentication enabled, and is set up for "Log in with Azure Active Directory".

The logic app keeps getting "Unauthorised" whenever it calls the azure function no matter what rights or roles I give the MSI.

Can anybody answer the simple question "Do logic apps support using their MSI to call azure functions?". If so, can you point me to some information about it. I can find precious little out there.

Comment: What is the `Authorization level` in the `Integrate` of your function?

Comment: It's currently on Function,  but I have tried all of them at various stages. The authorisation level seems to mostly determine where the key in the url comes from,  or if one is required. As far as I can tell, the AD authorisation happens before this check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, for anybody that is interested, the answer is "yes, kind of".

You can not use the Azure Function action as it doesn't support any kind of authentication other than going and getting the right key for you (if you're using keys).

You have to use the standard HTTP connector and wire the URL yourself (including the key in the URL or header if your function needs them). For authentication you can set the method to "Managed Identity", which I had seen and used but failed. What I didn't see was the normally hidden "Audience" parameter in to which you need to place the App Id (from Azure AD) of the function you are calling.

It now works, even if there is more manual wire up involved.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on the second sentence? Are you saying that if you are only using Function or Admin authorization, the Logic Apps call function action **does** automatically detect and use the key, and I don't need to do anything else? Would you know where this is documented? Thanks!

Comment: @TomW At the very least, for function level authorization (the default) the logic app function action does seem to be able to work out the key for itself (I dare say it calls the Azure management APIs under the covers). At least, in my use of it I never had to set the key myself. I haven't tried it with the Admin authorization level though.

Comment: This is my observation too. It bothers me slightly that this seems to be invisible with no apparent means of controlling or restricting it in any way, but it makes development easy, at least until unforseen issues arise.

Comment: @Boschy can you elaborate a bit on '"Audience" parameter in to which you need to place the App Id (from Azure AD) of the function you are calling' - I'm not aware if a function app gets it own AppId in Azure AD or you are talking about the App Id of the managed identity here?

Comment: @Sanjay, the Audience will depend on how authentication is set up on the Azure Function.

We currently use a manually created app registration that all of our Azure Functions use as the "ClientId" under the Azure Active Directory (Advanced) Settings. When doing it this way, the Audience needs to be the ClientId of that App Registration.

Alternatively, if you use the express setup for the function's authentication setup, then the Audience will most likely be the URL of the Azure Function itself. It could also possibly be the Client Id of the auto-generated App Registration.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination @Boschy, appreciate it. Makes sense.